# How to delete all data from SD Card

Tags: android

Please how can i delete all data from SD card (i mean format SD card) programatically . 
I tried to use this but it's only for one file .

```
File file = new File(selectedFilePath);
boolean deleted = file.delete();
```

Comment: Can I have name of your app?

Comment: Why would you even want that???

Comment: It's an app to secure your data when your device is stolen !! 
Don't think negatively !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its working fine for me.

This code can be used to delete all the files from the SD-Card. Hope it should work. Thanks.

```
public void wipingSdcard() {
    File deleteMatchingFile = new File(Environment
            .getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
    try {
        File[] filenames = deleteMatchingFile.listFiles();
        if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
            for (File tempFile : filenames) {
                if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                    wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                    tempFile.delete();
                } else {
                    tempFile.delete();
                }
            }
        } else {
            deleteMatchingFile.delete();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void wipeDirectory(String name) {
    File directoryFile = new File(name);
    File[] filenames = directoryFile.listFiles();
    if (filenames != null && filenames.length > 0) {
        for (File tempFile : filenames) {
            if (tempFile.isDirectory()) {
                wipeDirectory(tempFile.toString());
                tempFile.delete();
            } else {
                tempFile.delete();
            }
        }
    } else {
        directoryFile.delete();
    }
}
```

Also you have to give permission if you are using >1.6 SDK

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

in **AndroidManifest.xml** file