# How to delete the User accounts (Gmail, Facebook) Info and data saved in Android phone programmatic-ally?

Tags: android, user-accounts

I am developing a project which needs to delete/erase the user accounts like Login info and data of Facebook, Twitter, Gmail in Android Device. Need opinions from you...

Comment: You can't do. You can not delete an account programatically until the account type is your own..

Comment: yes i want to delete my own Account and this one is for Making a Anti-Theft Application.

Comment: Gmail/ Facebook is not your Account Type. I am not saying about account.

Comment: What i need to do is remove all the fb/twitter account info/data saved.Help Needed.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this way,i tried on gmail its working for me and its become clear the gmail apss and no history of log in etc
you will just log out but dont know what do you mean by delete?

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account[] accounts = am.getAccounts();
if (accounts.length > 0) {
    Account accountToRemove = accounts[0];
    am.removeAccount(accountToRemove, null, null);
}
```

Add the following permission as well

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```